# Is it possible to have an array as the elements of an array?

Tags: java, arrays

Is it possible to have an array as the elements of an array?
For example in the first index it can have an array of size 3, and the second index it can have an array of size 40.

I want to know if you can have an array as elements because 2 dimensional arrays doesn't allow for the columns or rows to be able to have more than one dimesnion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, absolutely!  The feature you're looking for is called "jagged arrays", and it works exactly the way you expect.

```
int arr[][] = new int[3][];   
arr[0] = new int[3];     
arr[1] = new int[40]; 
arr[2] = new int[12];
```

Source:  http://way2java.com/arrays/jagged-arrays-varying-column-size-arrays/

Answer (score 7):

Yes, that's what a "multi-dimensional" array in Java really is. It's an array of array references. Some of those references can be null, and the others can be of different sizes.

For example:

```
int[][] array = new int[3][];
array[0] = new int[3];
array[1] = new int[40];
array[2] = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
Object[][] arrays = new Object[5][];
```

then initialize your sub arrays with the sizes you want. Something like:

```
arrays[0] = new Object[3];
arrays[1] = new Object[5];
```

and so on

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, in most languages.
C, C++ and Java for sure.

For some languages, such as C or C++, the size of the arrays that are elements are not important.

Which language are you referring to?